# Why does C++ allow a function and a class have a same name?

Tags: c++, function, class, standards, language-design

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A()
    {
        cout << "A::A()" << endl;
    }
};

int A()
{
    cout << "void A()" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    auto v = A();
}
```

The output is:

> void A()

**Why does C++ allow a function and a class have a same name?**

Comment: The designer made that decision and nobody changed it ... not sure what other answer you are looking for.  Maybe it was for compatibility with C code or other existing code

Comment: I ask, why not? Just to not let people confuse themselves?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to Bjarne Stroustrup. Anything else is just more or less uninformed opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this comes down to backwards compatibility with C.

In C, when you declare a `struct` like you did, you then have to refer to it as `struct A`, not just `A`. For example:

```
void A() {}

struct A {};

void f()
{
    A();

    struct A x; // works fine
    A y; // does not compile
}
```

In this context, it makes sense to allow `A` to mean two different things, because it's always clear which one you mean, depending on whether you used `struct` or not.

In C++, `struct`s (and `class`es) can be referenced directly, without the need to use the `struct` keyword. This introduces the ambiguity you're concerned about, but the alternative is that valid C code like the one above would not be valid C++ code, which is even worse.

Comment: @downvoter Could you explain what do you think is wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Why? Because that's the way the language *is!*  The `A::A()` function belongs in a different "domain" than `A()`.

It's similar to namespaces, where the same name can exist in multiple domains.

It's also somewhat similar to having a thousand different functions (or scopes) all having their own loop counter called `i`.

Comment: It's very different. The OP actually showed an example where the class `A` would usually have been in scope, but was shadowed by the function `A`. Now of course variables can be shadowed, too, but only if they're in different scopes. Here the class `A` and the function `A` are both global, so the same thing would not be allowed for variables.

Comment: @sepp2k, a dog can be like a cat in one way (mammalia) and yet be different in another (canis/felis). That's why I was careful in using the term domain. The shadowing in this case is only of the `A` symbol, you can still get at both of them. I'll change the wording to hopefully alleviate your concerns.